# "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method" error when using Android NumberFormatter

Tags: android, kotlin, numberformatter

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/number/NumberFormatter) this line should produce an output of "// 1,234 in en-US":

```
println(NumberFormatter.withLocale(ULocale.ENGLISH).format(123).toString())
```

Instead it's throwing this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method withLocale(Landroid/icu/util/ULocale;)Landroid/icu/number/LocalizedNumberFormatter; in class Landroid/icu/number/NumberFormatter; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.icu.number.NumberFormatter' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Added in API level 30`

It works on android 11+. What's your version?

Comment: Android version 10 API 29, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Would you happen to know equivalent code samples for API < 30?

Comment: You can try to use icu4j directly: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j